# Can you use the 'order!' string in the require.js paths object to avoid repeating it in every dependency array?

Tags: backbone.js, require, requirejs

With require.js, can you specify the order! plugin to be used within the 'paths' config object?  I'm trying to avoid having to type 'order!' for several base modules that I always want included in a certain order.

My config:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min',
        underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
        backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone-min',
        order: 'libs/require/plugins/order'
    }
});
```

I tried it this way, but it included the 'order!' string in the actual path it was looking up.

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'order!libs/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min',
        underscore: 'order!libs/underscore/underscore-min',
        backbone: 'order!libs/backbone/backbone-min',
        order: 'libs/require/plugins/order'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the AMD forks of [Backbone](https://github.com/amdjs/backbone) and [Underscore](https://github.com/amdjs/underscore), maintained by James Burke who created RequireJS.  If you use these versions then you won't have to use the order plugin!

[More info about these forks](http://tagneto.blogspot.com/2012/01/amd-support-for-underscore-and-backbone.html)...